# How to add String output to an array within a recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a recursive procedure to return a permutation of a string

I get the desired output printed to the console. However, I would like to add the output to an array to be able to work on it further. How can I achieve it?

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Permutation { 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        permute("A", "BCD");
    }

    public static void permute(String FirstElement, String Remainder) {

        List<String> mylist_tobuild = new ArrayList<String>();      

        if (Remainder.length() <= 1) {
            FirstElement =  FirstElement+Remainder;
            //  System.out.println(FirstElement);

            mylist_tobuild.add(FirstElement);
            System.out.println(mylist_tobuild);
        }
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < Remainder.length(); i++) {
                try {
                  String newString = Remainder.substring(0, i) + Remainder.substring(i + 1);
                  permute(FirstElement + Remainder.charAt(i), newString);
                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                  exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
    } 
}
```

I get: [ABCD] [ABDC] [ACBD] [ACDB] [ADBC] [ADCB]

I would like to have: [ABCD, ABDC, ACBD, ACDB, ADBC, ADCB,]

Answer (score 4):

You can supply the `List` as an argument:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();
    permute("A", "BCD",perms);
    System.out.println(perms);
}

public static void permute(String FirstElement, String Remainder, List<String> perms) {

    if (Remainder.length() <= 1) {
        FirstElement =  FirstElement+Remainder;
        perms.add(FirstElement);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < Remainder.length(); i++) {
            try {
                String newString = Remainder.substring(0, i) + Remainder.substring(i + 1);
                permute(FirstElement + Remainder.charAt(i), newString, perms);
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, this was the missing link to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new list every time you go through the permute method. To fix that, you can take your list creation out of the method (e.g. create a static field), so you don't create a new list every time you go through the loop. Then add your print statement after your permutation method in your main class, so you can get the final result.

```
    private static ArrayList<String> mylist_tobuild;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        mylist_tobuild = new ArrayList<>(); //initialize list here once
        permute("A", "BCD");
        System.out.println(mylist_tobuild);
    }
```